# loading images from html /wordpress using php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I am trying to load an image file to my wordpress space using code from W3Schools.

However, `move_uploaded_file` fails.

I have peppered the site with `php.ini` containing `file_uploads = On`

I have set file permissions on the target directory to 777.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you *peppered the site with php.ini containing file_uploads = On*? Also, what is the code that you're using to move the file, surrounding the `move_uploaded_file` function? Please post your code!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that dosent work

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

}

I put php.ini in the perticular plugin folder and wordpress base folder